# Q learning computation: states unknown

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am confused about how to implement a simple q_learning algorithm.
I am referring to this nice docummentation: http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_265.html.

The given formula is

```
Q[s,a] ←Q[s,a] + α(r+ γmaxa' Q[s',a'] - Q[s,a])
```

The problem is that the states are unknown because I am trying to learn [Flappybird's](http://nebez.github.io/floppybird/) successful moves. To get `Q[s,a]` I need to know the value of `Q[s',a']` but if I don't know the next state, how do I get the Q function? Assuming that the state is described by the distance between the bird and the nearest pipe, how would you compute the current Q function?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`s'` is the current state. `s` is the previous state. `max_a' Q[s', a']` is the value of the best action the current state.